# How to determine if I am "off course" on Android MapView

Tags: android, android-maps

So, I have plotted a GPX route in my MapView, and I am listening for location changes.

Ultimately I want to give my user notification when they are off/on course.

So, I can imagine just brute-force going through all my GPX coordinates and do a Location.distanceTo for each for each of them. But that seems expensive.

I could reduce the cost by doing it infrequently.

I am wondering if someone has a clever idea for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `distanceTo` but not inside `onLocationChanged` (because it is called very frequent) , you should do a timer and check if the user going off course in each 5 seconds (for example), this is how to implement the timer:

1- declare this as global variable:

```
private Timer myTimer;
```

2- add this code in your `onCreate()`:

```
                myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TimerMethod();
                    }

                }, 0, 5000);
```

3- add these two functions in your class:

```
     private void TimerMethod()
        {
            this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
        }

     private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //do your test for off course here
            }
        };
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would probably keep track of three coordinates: Last, Current, Next.  You can calculate the distance and direction from Last to Current and the location and direction the user is going and come up with some algorithm to ensure the user is going the right way (ensure that the user is approaching Current, ensure that they're within some distance of the line from Last to Current, etc.)

Then at some point you need to realize that the user has come as close as they're ever going to towards Current and are now heading for Next.  Then you'll shift the points down (`Last = Current; Current = Next; Next = ???;`).  Again there are a number of ways you could make this determination (user has gotten close enough to Current, user is heading towards Next and away from Current, etc.)

You might want to include some look-ahead in case you miss a few points, especially when points are close together, but you don't want to do too much.  Test your route with loops in the paths and make sure you don't jump ahead.  You'll probably also need to implement some sort of `holyExpletiveIHaveNoIdeaWhereTheUserIsGoing()` method to recover from the (inevitable) errors.